# confusion concerning function definitions

Tags: function, comparison, definition

I'm really new to coding and I was wonder if the **function definition** `void some_thing( char *thing)` would be equivalent to `void some_thing( char thing[])`.

I know, for example, ar[i] is equivalent to *(ar+i) but I wasn't sure if they were equivalent as function definitions.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are equivalent when used in function parameters.Elements can be accessed either by array notation i.e. thing[i] or by pointers( *(thing+n) ) inside the function.